# NCalc allows me to use { } [ ] in a math operation?

Tags: c#, math, ncalc

So, I want to give the answer of 
{ [ 4+(3+2)]}
I already have this in a String, but when i tried to use DataTable, it give me error..
Or another way to calculate it with the { } [ ] 
Thanks

Comment: From my understanding braces and brackets just more ordering to the expression.  Do you have an example of an expression that can't be done with just parenthesis?

Comment: Mmm... you are right! Will change the {} [] with () thanks! :D

Answer (score 1):

When evaluating simple arithmetic expressions, `[]` or `{}` are just a notational variant of `()` to make matching parentheses easier. So you could simply replace them by `()` and then proceed with that.

There are many corners in Mathematics where these symbols would mean completely different things, e.g. `[]` for floor, equivalence class, vector, … or `{}` for fractional part, set, … So it would be wrong to say that *any* mathematical expression retains its semantics by the above replacement. Be sure you know what kinds of expressions you're dealing with.